# How many instances of a list are present in each value of a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

Using python and pandas, I'd like to know how many different Brands (within the brand_List) are present in each value in Col_1 of my df

**My List_of_Brands:**

```
brand_List = ["Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3"]
```

**My df + desired output:**

```
    Col_1           |  Desired_Col_2 
Brand1_bla_Brand2   |     2
Brand3              |     1
bla_bla             |     0
Brand2_Brand3       |     2
Brand2_Brand3_Brand1|     3
```

I hope this makes sense,

Thanks a lot in advance for your thoughts and help,
Alex

Comment: `df["Desired_Col_2"] = df["Col_1"].str.count("|".join(brand_List))` ?

Comment: Heyy @Timeless thank you but actually, I made a mistake, I need to know many unique instances of brands are present. Therefore if in Col_1 I have Brand1_bla_Brand1 it should be equal to 1. (Sorry for the lack of clarity)

Comment: Maybe `df["Col_1"].str.findall("|".join(brand_List)).apply(pd.unique).str.len()` ?